# plt.show() not working in pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am using pycharm after upgrading my python to python 3.5.

I re-run a standard code that i had in place and had a problem with `plt.show()`
example:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.show()
```

The suggestion by `DavidG` made things worked fine. But this time when I do

```
       import matplotlib
        matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
        plt.show()
```

i get an error saying

```
/apps/qtrinst/install/python/anaconda/envs/sx_anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py:1401: UserWarning:  This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect
because the backend has already been chosen;
matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.
```

It didnt get this error before-not sure what happened there.

Comment: Are you using the backend `WebAgg` on purpose?

Comment: @DavidG not i am not. I dont even know what WebAgg is to be honest. When I run python, the first message i get on the console is "Backend WebAgg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on." i have never paid any attention to this message until i started plotting. Then I realised that maybe that message is trying to say something important regarding plotting :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is with your "backend". The documentation has a section entitled "[What is a backend?](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend)" which will be helpful.

I'm not familiar with `WebAgg` but I don't think you want to be using it. A more conventional one might be `TkAgg` which requires `Tkinger` or `Qt4Agg` which requires `PyQt4`. You can switch backends using

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")  # Do this before importing pyplot!
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a different Backend. It worked for me when I used *QtAgg*

#### PyQt

you will need to install some version of PyQt. At the moment:

```
pip install PyQt6
```

#### Specify the GUI backend

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("QtAgg")
```

#### Try `plt.show()`

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# some code here

plt.show()
```

*This worked flawlessly for me. Hope It worked for you too.*