# Python PyCharm figure bag! plt.figure\plot stops working in debug mode, but works on the Python console

Tags: python, matplotlib, ubuntu, pycharm, python-3.8

Happy New Year.

I am using the familiar matplotlib library, and out of nowhere, the figure stops working. Oddly enough, it functions properly only on the Python console in PyCharm, but not in debug. None of the interpreters that used to work still function.
PyCharm crashes while trying to load.

I am using ubuntu 18, PyCharm 2021.3.1, matplotlib library 3.5.1, Python 3.8/3.9/3.10
[image: figure screen capture]

I tried to reinstall PyCharm with no success.
Has anyone seen this thing before? Does anyone know how to handle it?

Thank you.

Comment: I've faced this problem many times, but on Windows. I think you need to kill the process completely. On Linux, if you DON'T have any important processes (like refactoring?) running in PyCharm, I think you should end the PyCharm task using `Ctrl+Alt+Del` or any other method/shortcut using the task manager. (Use the task manager to close PyCharm, and then reopen PyCharm)

Comment: Does [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004382380-Matplotlib-doesn-t-show-plots-in-new-window) help?

Comment: thank you, but unfortunately  killing the process didn't do the trick

Answer (score 3):

I checked the difference between the two debuggers.
one wrote it uses the `'TkAgg'` backend and not the `'QtAgg'`

[image]

this solved it!

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
```

thanks to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49918998/plt-show-not-working-in-pycharm).